# Face Detection Algorithm using Emgu CV

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-detection

Is there any method to dectecting face using emgu cv from just image?
I'm not looking using color segmentation method or from motion detect method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Haar Cascade Classifier Classifier. 
Here an example http://ahmedopeyemi.com/main/face-detection-and-recognition-in-c-using-emgucv-3-0-opencv-wrapper-part-1/.

And here a good (and concise) explanation on how HCC works and how to train your own classifier (for face detection you can find several good classifiers ready to use) http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html